# Standard form Linear Program

Tags: linear-programming

How do i convert this LP
$$\text{maximize  }x_4$$
$$\text{subject to  }\epsilon\leq x_1\leq 1\\\epsilon{x_{j-1}}\leq x_j\leq 1-\epsilon{x_{j-1}}, \quad j=2,...,4 $$
 to the standard form $$\text{minimize  } c^Tx\\\text{subject to  Ax=b}\\x\geq 0$$

Comment: So $x$ = <$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$>, right?

Comment: And therefore $c^T$ = ...?

Comment: Yes x = x1, x2, x3.  c is the coefficients of x1, x2, x3. so e.g: c^Tx = ax1+bx2+....

Comment: Yes, but $c^T$ is forced since you want the dot product to equal $x_4$. So you can write $c^T$ as what numerical $4$-tuple?

Comment: No, $x$ is not <$x_1,x_2,x_3$>. You need all 4 variables. Similarly, $c$ is a $4$-tuple, not a triple.

Comment: c^Tx = [0; 0; 0; 1]^T*[x1 x2 x3 x4] = x4

Comment: Right, good start.

Comment: Actually, a few more variables will be needed (slack variables), but that can be fixed later.

Comment: Before getting the matrix $A$, rewrite all the inequalities in $\le$ form, or, to save time, in equation form with slack variables.

Comment: ok. so do i break up the inequality to form two inequalities?

Comment: Yep. And the rest is easy.

Comment: When done, the vector $x$ has to be adjusted to incorporate the new slack variables. Similarly, $c^T$ has to be adjusted.

Comment: Each inequality gets its own private slack variable.

Comment: so for the first inequality i can write $$x_1\leq 1\quad x_1\geq \epsilon\\ x_1+\alpha=1\quad x_1-\beta=\epsilon$$

Comment: yes, you got it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can get $A$ now, right?

Comment: Yes. I can get A now

Comment: Just to check, what will the dimensions of $c,x,A,b$ be?

Comment: The new $x$ needs to include the slack variables.

Comment: $$c = m\times 1, \quad x = m\times 1, A= m\times m, b= m\times 1$$. yes x will include the slack variables

Comment: No, A is not square. Also, $m$ is not a variable -- it's a number.

Comment: Start with $x$. How many components does it have?

Comment: sorry. yes A is not square

Comment: So what is the dimension of the new $x$?

Comment: $x$ needs components for the old variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ as well as the new slack variables, There is one slack variable for each equation, hence the dimension of the new $x$ is [what]?